# How to calculate $\int_{|z|=\frac{3}{2}}\frac{z^{3}\cos z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

1-$$\int_{|z|=\frac{3}{2}}\frac{z^{3}\cos z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$$
My Attempt

$\int_{|z|=\frac{3}{2}}\frac{z^{3}\cos z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz=2\pi i\frac{1^{3}\cos 1}{(1-2)}=-2\pi i\,\cos 1$

2-$$\int_{|z|=3}\frac{\cos z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$$
My Attempt

$\int_{|z|=3}\frac{\cos z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz=\int_{|z|=3}\frac{\cos z}{(z-2)}dz-\int_{|z|=3}\frac{\cos z}{(z-1)}dz=2\pi i{\,\cos 2}-2\pi i{\,\cos 1}=2\pi i({\cos 2}-{\cos 1})$

3-$$\int_{|z-i|=4}\frac{e^z\cos z}{(z^2-2)}dz$$
My Attempt

$\int_{|z-i|=4}\frac{e^z\cos z}{(z^2-2)}dz=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{|z-i|=4}\frac{e^z\cos z}{(z-\sqrt{2})}dz-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{|z-i|=4}\frac{e^z\cos z}{(z+\sqrt{2})}dz=-\frac{2\pi i}{2\sqrt{2}}e^{\sqrt{2}}\cos (\sqrt{2})-\frac{2\pi i}{2\sqrt{2}}e^{-\sqrt{2}}\cos (-\sqrt{2})$

4-$$\int_{|z-i|=1}\frac{e^z}{(z^2+1)}dz$$
My Attempt

$\int_{|z-i|=1}\frac{e^z}{(z^2+1)}dz=\int_{|z-i|=1}\frac{e^z}{(z+i)(z-i)}dz=\frac{2\pi i e^z}{(i+i)}=\pi  e^i$

Are the above solutions correct?

Also, can the integral  $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{(z-1)}dz$ be solved using contour integration? I am confused because $z=1$ lies on the boundary of $|z|=1$.

Comment: In most cases, when the pole lies on the boundary, you can still solve with residue theorem. Just use $\pi i$ rather than $2 \pi i$

Comment: @Kaynex, so the answer will be $\pi i e$. Is that right?

Comment: @Kaynex, what about the other integrals are they correct?

Comment: Did not check in minute detail but everything looks right at first glance.